# Changing frame of presented navigation view controller from custom UIPresentation Controller not changing bounds of navigation controller childrens

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, custom-transition, uipresentationcontroller

I am presenting a navigation controller with custom transition and custom presentation controller. Presentation controller listen for keyboard, and change presented view controller frame accordingly.

In first screen keyboard is active so presented view controller use smaller frame
[image: In first screen keyboard is active so presented view controller use smaller frame]

I have set red background for navigation controller. When 2nd screen comes it dismiss keyboard, and the frame of presented view controller is increased. Although navigation controller frame changes as require it doesn't change frame for its children views

[image: I have set red background for navigation controller. When 2nd screen comes it dismiss keyboard, and the frame of presented view controller is increased. Although navigation controller frame changes as require it doesn't change frame for its children views]

Any idea how can i fix this issue